# Changed device DPI now stuck in a bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, twrp

- Device: OnePlus One
- ROM: MultiROM with CM11s as internal, and CM12 nightly as secondary
- Recovery: TWRP
- Backup location: USB OTG
- Backup method: Online Nandroid Backup application

---

So I have quite a dilemma on my hands. I wanted to try something, so I installed a root DPI changing app. I must have set it incorrectly because when I rebooted, everything was so large that I couldn't even unlock the device.

So I followed the application's advice, I copied the `build.prop` backup to `/system`. And I went into a boot loop. Then I tried copying the stock `build.prop` for my device to `/system`, but it didn't help any.

Everything else seems to work fine. I have TWRP installed, and I have a good backup, but it's on a USB drive, and the data partition is ~6.5GB, so it won't go back on my phone. So here are my options, as I see them:

1. Fix `build.prop`, of which I don't have the original file.

   - Problems:

     - I have no idea how to do that.
2. Restore from my TWRP backup.

   - Problems:

     - I have the backup on a USB drive.
     - TWRP doesn't seem to want to recognize that there is a backup on the USB OTG.
     - The data file is 6.94GB (over Android's 4GB file size limit), so I can't move it back.
3. Dirty re-flash the OS while keeping my data.

   - Problems:

     - I don't know how to do that.
     - I've heard that problems persist if that's done.
4. Wipe *everything* and start from scratch.

   - Problems:

     - Obviously, I don't want to do that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119021/discussion-on-question-by-j-m-g-r-changed-device-dpi-now-stuck-in-a-bootloop).

Answer (score 3):

The reason for a boot loop after editing `build.prop` is its permissions.

Just go to TWRP > Advanced > File Manager and navigate to `/system/build.prop`. Select it and change its permissions to `-rw-r--r--`. To do that, enter `0644` in `chmod` and reboot your device.

If you cannot see `build.prop` in `/system` folder, go to Mounts and select System in the TWRP home menu.

Answer (score 1):

If the `build.prop` is the problem, you could try fixing permissions:

- Restore `build.prop` from backup
- Go to TWRP/Advanced and choose **Fix permissions**

If you want to restore your TWRP backup:

- In TWRP, do a factory reset
- Boot up the system and copy the TWRP backup to the internal SD card (if you got enough space). That should be formatted with ext4 or something like that, not FAT32.
- Boot to recovery and restore the backup.

*or*

- Just reflash the `ROM.zip`. That should fix all problems without deleting `/data`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this problem is solved but for future reference, I will post these two options:

- Push the original `build.prop` via ADB when on TWRP

  1. Plug the device into your PC
  2. Open a CMD or a terminal (depends on your OS)
  3. Write this commands

     ```
     adb kill-server
     adb root
     adb remount
     adb push original-build.prop /system/build.prop
     ```

Or

- Grab the current `build.prop`, edit the density, and then push it back

  1. Grab it by using `adb pull /system/build.prop /path/to/build.prop`
  2. Edit the `build.prop`
  3. Then push it back

     ```
     adb kill-server
     adb root
     adb remount
     adb push edited-build.prop /system/build.prop
     ```

Answer (score 0):

So, I actually ended up flashing only the `system.img` and `boot.img` files, and that let the device turn on.

There were a few problems I ran into, though. Settings kept force quitting, for one thing. But I was able to make a fresh Helium backup, so then I wiped everything and started over. After spending a bit of time restoring some files, my One is running well again.